# XSLT selected value datatype

Tags: xslt

How do I check the type of selected value in XSLT.I am trying to validate my XML against and XSD and if the value if is of real type , then I will add the node

Comment: By "real type" to you mean "correct type", or "floating-point numeric type?"

Answer (score 1):

XSLT 2.0 allows you to validate an element (including a newly constructed element) against a schema, for example

```
<xsl:import-schema namespace="abc.xyz" schema-location="file://temp.xsd"/>

<xsl:template ...>
   <xsl:element name="x" validation="strict">
     ...
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Unfortunately there's no way of catching the error if it's invalid. However, Saxon has a try/catch extension for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I check the type of selected value in XSLT?

**An XSLT 2.0 Schema-aware (SA) processor can validate against a schema** source XML files, output result files, intermediary trees, parameters and variable values, return values from functions or from applying/calling templates.

**XSLT 1.0 uses XPath 1.0 which is not strongly typed and has only a few standard types**.

> I am trying to validate my XML against and XSD and if the value if is
>   of real type , then I will add the node

This is much easier than validating against a schema.

**In [XPath 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-instance-of) (XSLT 2.0) use**:

```
$yourVar instance of xs:double
```

**In XPath 1.0 (XSLT 1.0) use**:

```
number($yourVar) = number($yourVar)
```